# Can't set a wrapper div to a height when an inner div is repositioned. Problem in IE6 only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6

I have two div's with fixed heights wrapped by a div with a fixed height. When I reposition one of the div's, the wrapper keeps the original height which is the sum of the inner div's heights. I want the wrapper div to have a height of 240 as declared in the CSS but it's not working in IE6.

It works fine in IE7, IE8 and other browsers.

Here's a working demo at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EdXqx/5/).

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#wrapper').height(240);
         $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#div2').position({
                my: "left top",
                at: "left top",
                of: $('#wrapper'),
                offset: "40 10"
            });

           $('#wrapper').height(240);

        });
    </script>

    <div id="wrapper" style="height: 240px;border: 1px solid red;overflow:none">
         <div id="div1" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;border: 1px solid green">
             Div 1</div>
         <div id="div2" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;border: 1px solid blue">
             Div 2</div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I can't resist...http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Answer (score 0):

The overflow: none is supposed to be overflow: hidden which fixed it.